# View loading and binding to commands dynamically in MVVM model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a main window :

```
<Window>
  <Grid>
   <Grid x:Name="Container"/>
   <local:bottompanel x:Name="BP"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The content of container changed during the application flow. Each time I am loading another view into it. I have two questions :

1. What is the "right" way to do load those views. 
   I used this code to do this :

   ```
   UIElement uie = new MyView1();
   Container.Children.Add(uie);
   ```

   Is there another, more acceptable way to do this?
2. I want datacontext of the bottom panel to be the datacontext of the current loaded view.
   How can I do this ?

Comment: you can use a datatemplate to hold the view and switch the view using the datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you currectly , what you can do something like this.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:vm1}">
view one
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:vm2}">
view Two
</DataTemplate>
```

And in your mainwindow.xaml

```
 <Window>
 <Grid>
 <Grid x:Name="Container"/>
  <ContentControl  Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Grid>
```

And in your MainviewModel create a property CurrentView

```
private ViewModelBase currentview;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get
        {
            return currentview;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentview != value)
            {
                currentview = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }
    }
```

set the CurrentView to approperiate viewmodel inside your "View Switching" logic